# Uninstall capistrano and install particular version in ruby-1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano

I am working application of `ruby-1.8.7` for client.

I got error when tried to deploy on staging using  `cap staging deploy` command.

Right now, `installed capistrano-3.2.1 version`. Now, i want to `remove it and install capistrano-2.5.19 version.`

How to `change version of capistrano` or uninstall it and install new.

How to install capistrano for ruby-1.8.7 compatible verions.

```
I got every time ERROR: error installing capistrano. highline required ruby version >= 1.9.3
```

Thanks

/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/capistrano-3.2.1

Comment: `gem unistall capistrano` ?

Comment: which version install in ruby-1.8.7 compatible version?

Answer (score 9):

```
$ gem uninstall capistrano

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. capistrano-2.12.0
 2. capistrano-3.5.0
 3. All versions
> 2
Successfully uninstalled capistrano-3.5.0
```